# Estimate 3D orientation of plane in 2D image

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera

Is it possible to estimate the 3D orientation of a plane using a single 2D image?

Assuming the plane is rectangular and perpendicular to the ground (like a wall), and the ground is described by a plane z = 0, I would like to **find the angle between the viewing direction and the plane**.

The intrinsic parameters of the camera are known. I have been looking into using vanishing lines to estimate the orientation but can't really figure out how I can use these to estimate the orientation of the plane.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have some known point on the plane? If you have vanishing lines you can rotate the camera until the lines follow some usable direction (e.g. horizontal).

Comment: I can find the pixel coordinates of the corners of the plane, but the 3D positions of these are unknown. My current approach is iteratively rotating the camera until the vanishing lines of the same vanishing point are parallel. This is when the viewing direction is perpendicular with the plane.

Comment: from the iterative rotation you afterwards know the rotation angles. Those are your plane angles (or their inverse).

Comment: do you know the size of the plane (e.g. real distance between the corners)?

Comment: Yes, the size of the plane is known

Comment: so you can describe the corners in real world plane-coordinate-system, e.g. (0,0),(0,2m),(5m,2m),(5m,0)? Then you can use cv::solvePnp to get the object pose relative to the camera, but you'll need the camera intrinsics. But I am not sure whether 4 points are sufficient...